# How to get last 7 days records with 0 counts

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent query that gets the total count records (created_at) of the last 7 days. But the problem is if one of these days have 0 records, this doesn't appear in the final data.

My query:

```
$data = Data::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subDays(6)->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00", Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')." 23:59:59"])
             ->groupBy('date')
             ->orderBy('date')
             ->get([
                 DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'),
                 DB::raw('count(*) as total')
             ])
             ->pluck('total', 'date')->toArray();
```

What I get:

```
[    
    "2020-04-14" => 1
    "2020-04-16" => 1
    "2020-04-18" => 1
    "2020-04-19" => 1
]
```

What I expected:

```
[    
    "2020-04-14" => 1    
    "2020-04-15" => 0
    "2020-04-16" => 1    
    "2020-04-17" => 0
    "2020-04-18" => 1
    "2020-04-19" => 1    
    "2020-04-20" => 0
]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to create a `for` loop to check the days.

If there is no record on a date then print `0`

Loop Iteration:

- Catch the first Day (Suppose 14)
- Catch the last Day
- Then check in every iteration it is greater than one or many

Thus, I hope you will get normally.

Comment: Thanks! But this is my last option, I'm trying to find a automatic option. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem while trying to put back-end data into the chart. Since some of the days were missing it didn't look well. Our solution was;

Create a function like this;

```
public function generateDates(Date $startDate, Date $endDate, $format = 'Y/m/d'): Collection
{
    $dates = collect();
    $startDate = $startDate->copy();

    for ($date = $startDate; $date->lte($endDate); $date->addDay()) {
        $dates->put($date->format($format), 0);
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

In your case it's going to be (today and today - six days) and you will `union` returning collection with your query collection. What it does is; it create a date range from the keys and fill them with zero. When your query collection has some value other than zero - it is going to overwrite it.

Comment: Yes, I have something similar to collect de dates of the previous 6 days from today. Later, for use in the solution propossed by @Mr. Perfectionist.
I've added the solution int the post, if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Originally posted by OP as an edit to the question, where answers do not belong:

---

**Solution**

-Based on Gary Houbre's proposal:

```
$results = Data::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subDays(6)->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00", Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')." 23:59:59"])
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->orderBy('date')
    ->get([
        DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as date'),
        DB::raw('count(*) as total')
    ])
    ->keyBy('date')
    ->map(function ($item) {
        $item->date = Carbon::parse($item->date);
        return $item;
    });

$period = new DatePeriod(Carbon::now()->subDays(6), CarbonInterval::day(), Carbon::now()->addDay());

$graph = array_map(function ($datePeriod) use ($results) {
    $date = $datePeriod->format('Y-m-d');
    return $results->has($date) ? $results->get($date)->total : 0;

}, iterator_to_array($period));
```