# laravel chartjs dates skipped

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js

can someone help me please.. i have database with activities members and want to display in chartjs last 7 days data.

```
id member_id bonus created_at
1    1         3     2020-04-16
2    1         3     2020-04-17
3    1         7     2020-04-18
4    1         5     2020-04-19
5    1         15    2020-04-20
6    1         10    2020-04-21
7    1         9     2020-04-22 
8    1         11    2020-04-24
```

my laravel code

```
$chart = charts::where('member_id', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->where('created_at', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::today()->subDays(7))->get();

$bonus = [];
foreach ($charts as $index => $count) {
            $bonus[] = [$count->bonus];
        }
return view('index', ['bonus' => $bonus]);
```

problem is in chart because display data from **2020-04-17** to **2020-04-24** and it's logic, but i want to show also in chart days when member don't have any bonus for example **2020-04-23** not exists because member didn't have bonus this day, so i need to show in chart 0 in 2020-04-23.

can someone help me ?

Comment: can you please check this answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/61323748/2188922

Comment: thanks, but my case is not similar to this answer.

Comment: @Ersoy can i ask my last question please if i have another column field in table like "bonus" for example another field named "type" and i want to include it with dates created_at in query in get() and pluck the same you did for "bonus" please how i can do that ? thanks so much my friend for help...

Comment: put `type` in `get`, `$activities->pluck('bonus', 'date')` and `$activities->pluck('type', 'date')`. the answer is locked - this is my final answer because i made a real-time development in comments. hope you understand. good luck

Comment: how please do i need to have two get and pluck in my query ? please if u can post final query please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your `created_at` column is `timestamp` (formatting added for that case)

```
public function index()
{
    $start = Carbon::today()->subDays(7);
    $end = Carbon::yesterday();

    $activities = Activity::where('member_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today()->subDays(7))
        ->get(['bonus', DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') as date")])
        ->pluck('bonus', 'date');

    $dates = $this->generateDates($start, $end); // you fill zero valued dates

    return $dates->merge($activities); // overwrite your bonuses with the zero values
}

public function generateDates(Carbon $startDate, Carbon $endDate, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $dates = collect();
    $startDate = $startDate->copy();

    for ($date = $startDate; $date->lte($endDate); $date->addDay()) {
        $dates->put($date->format($format), 0);
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

to format dates

```
$formattedDates = $dates->merge($activities)
            ->keys()
            ->transform(function ($date) {
                return Carbon::parse($date)->format('d F');
            });
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212463/discussion-on-answer-by-ersoy-laravel-chartjs-dates-skipped).